# Passing value to countdowntimer() in android

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I have the user inputting the time in the countdown timer.
Right now, its fixed to 10sec. How can i change this to user input ?

```
CountDownTimer counter = new CountDownTimer(10000,1000) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        //millisUntilFinished=20000;
        settime.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        quescount++;
        if (quescount%5==0){
            round ++;
            rndno.setText(String.valueOf(round));
         //  onBackPressed();
        }
        quescounter.setText("Out of "+String.valueOf(quescount));
              //  j = randomcount(getcount(),1);
                ++qcounter;
                //j=qcounter;
                if (qcounter<count)
                setdata(String.valueOf(list.get(qcounter)));
                else
                {
                    Collections.shuffle(list);
                    qcounter=0;
                    setdata(String.valueOf(list.get(qcounter)));
                }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Call this method where you take the input from the user:

```
 public void startCountDown(long duration) {

    CountDownTimer counter = new CountDownTimer(duration, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            //millisUntilFinished=20000;
            settime.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            quescount++;
            if (quescount%5==0){
                round ++;
                rndno.setText(String.valueOf(round));
             //  onBackPressed();
            }
            quescounter.setText("Out of "+String.valueOf(quescount));
                  //  j = randomcount(getcount(),1);
                    ++qcounter;
                    //j=qcounter;
                    if (qcounter<count)
                    setdata(String.valueOf(list.get(qcounter)));
                    else
                    {
                        Collections.shuffle(list);
                        qcounter=0;
                        setdata(String.valueOf(list.get(qcounter)));
                    }
        }
    };
}
```

You'll probably want to make your `CountDownTimer` variable global as well.